# SQL Server version not supported by this release of Upgrade Advisor

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

We have a SQL Server 2000 database in production running on SQL Server 2000 instance. But in our staging environment, we have this same database on a SQL Server 2008 instance but running under compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000).

We need to upgrade the production database to SQL Server 2008, so I'm trying to run the SQL Server Upgrade Advisor 2008 on my staging copy. But I'm getting this error:

> SQL Server version: 10.00.2531 is not supported by this release of Upgrade Advisor, only SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005 are supported.

My goal is to know what might happen if I change the compatibility level to 100 (SQL Server 2008). How can I get Upgrade Advisor to tell me under my circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, Upgrade Advisor doesn't work for that; I don't know of a tool that automatically compares compatibility modes.  The best reference I know of is this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.100).aspx

Which will show you breaking changes between level 80=>90 and level 90=>100.

I should also state that upgrading to SQL 2008 should NOT be your final stop; with SQL 2016 looming on the horizon, you should investigate moving up to at least SQL 2014.